# Correct SQL Server Index When Selecting one parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server that looks something like this:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM Message m
WHERE m.id IN (someIds)
    AND m.creationTime >= someDate
    AND m.partition_number IN (0,1)
```

My Question is which kind of index should be best for this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just use index on ID Column.

Comment: Thanks For Answer. Are you sure that it is enough ? I mean I have 3 conditions in where statement. Do not I need the index on other columns ?

Comment: Depends on the stored data. (E.g. if almost all m.partition_number's are either 0 or 1, an index makes no difference.)

Comment: I understood m.partition_number' are either 0,1 or 2 so I don't need index on this column. What about date ?

Comment: @jarlh, I agree it depends on the stored data.  However, even if every row has partition_number 0 or 1, an index on id, someDate, or both may improve query performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that id is the primary key on the Message table (if it's not, you're going to get a lot of people having trouble following your code).

The PK will be a Clustered index: that is, it's not separate from the data the index points to. Find the key and the data associated with it is stored with it. For a non-clustered index (such as might exist on creationTime) what's stored with the key is a pointer to data, and the server then has to go away and do another disc access to read the data. Thus clustered indexes are more efficient than non-clustered ones as you only have to find the key.

If you can specify the PK values (the someIds in your query) it will be as efficient as possible, and adding an index on creationTime will not improve it. Indeed, if SQL Server used it as well as the PK then it would degrade the query.

So as long as id is the PK you are doing as well as possible.

Final comment: what you are doing is called Premature Optimisation and is generally a no-no. With databases, do not try too hard to improve performance until you KNOW you have a problem and can measure it. Then you get out the Query Plan for the query which is slow and start playing about it. Until then, knowing what queries your app is issuing will give a very good first approximation of what indexes you will need and you shouldn't try too hard to optimise them until you know there is a problem.

Comment: Simon, Thanks for answer. The problem is that, id is not PK, because there is another column messageId which is PK. So In That case I have performance problem without index. Now My question is what is better for having good performance: 1. Create Index on Id column 2. Create Index on Id, date column 3. Create Index on Id, date and partition_number column

Comment: I'd guess on id + creationDate. The thing is NOT to index on a column that changes, as this can cause the index to have to re-order itself, so I'm assuming that id and creationDate don't change. With SQL Server you can include fields with the index which aren't part of the index so that if the field changes it doesn't mean the index has to be re-organised. You could include partition_number in this way. However, SSMS has a really good feature: you can tell it to show the expected query plan. The latter option will suggest indexes that will help the query - a very useful feature.